# Fazer uma query

Tags: wordpress

Bom dia , estou iniciando agora no wordpress , não tenho muita experiencia,por exemplo eu tenho formulário de nome e email, e eu gostaria de fazer uma query para que estes dados fossem inseridos na tbl_usuarios por exemplo.. como eu iria fazer? existe alguma classe do wp para usar? estou com muitas duvidas em relação a fazer querys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia meu caro, você realmente possui a necessidade de trabalhar com um banco de dados utilizando Wordpress?

Pois o Wordpress possui inúmeros plugins para atender estas necessidades simples, para que você não precise de intervenções manuais.

Para trabalhar com fomulário há o plugin contact form 7 e o wp-mail smtp que atende a uma necessidade muito boa para que não precise reiventar a roda.

Estou a disposição!

Comment: Então mano , é o seguinte eu até vi sobre alguns plugins mas no caso por exemplo preciso fazer cadastro de usuario para este usuario poder fazer "postagem" de por exemplo com titulo imagem , descricao preco etc.  e tambem outra funcao seria o cara filtrar determinadas postagens de acordo com a cidade que ele escolher e tal , por isso achei q seria ideal fazer essas querys , eu tenho uma boa nocao com html css e php mas eu não sei como aplicar no wp

Comment: Tem um plugin que se chama insert_php come ele voce poder inserir seus codigos php nas paginas wp, pois recomendo voce nao ficar inserindo codigo nos arquivos do wp, sem ter o prévio conhecimento.